# flutter: Need either specifiedType or discriminator field

Tags: dart, flutter

everyone,i'm confuse on this problem few days,any one can help me?
 when i using flutter redux,i got this problems.

> Deserializing '[data, {accounts: [], version: 5.4}, null, null]' to 'LoginResponse' failed due to: Invalid 
>    argument(s): Unknown type on deserialization. Need either specifiedType or discriminator field.

**here is LoginResponse Deserialize method:**

```dart
    LoginResponse deserialize(Serializers serializers, Iterable serialized,
      {FullType specifiedType: FullType.unspecified}) {
    final result = new LoginResponseBuilder();
    final iterator = serialized.iterator;
    while (iterator.moveNext()) {
      final key = iterator.current as String;
      iterator.moveNext();
      final dynamic value = iterator.current;
      switch (key) {
        case 'data':
          result.data.replace(serializers.deserialize(value, specifiedType: const FullType(LoginResponseData)) as LoginResponseData);
          break;
        case 'error':
          result.error.replace(serializers.deserialize(value,
              specifiedType: const FullType(ErrorMessage)) as ErrorMessage);
          break;
      }
    }

    return result.build();
  }

abstract class LoginResponseData implements Built<LoginResponseData, LoginResponseDataBuilder> {

  factory LoginResponseData([void updates(LoginResponseDataBuilder b)]) = _$LoginResponseData;
  LoginResponseData._();

  BuiltList<CompanyEntity> get accounts;
  String get version;
  static Serializer<LoginResponseData> get serializer => _$loginResponseDataSerializer;
}
```

What really hurts me is that the debugging mode of android studio seems some problem? some variable always shows "Collecting data... it's hard to me to fix this problem cause i can't got some key variable's value.just like:specifiedType.

**There is some screenshot when debuging.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

i'm great appreciate if any one could give me some tips or answers!!! thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link -> https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/1172
I hope you'll find your answer here.